# How to setup open_basedir in PHP for Joomla

Tags: joomla, open-basedir

I am trying to setup `open_basedir` on the php.ini file on the server however I'm not really sure how.

Do I create a directory somewhere on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **check the current status** in Joomla! Administrator, under Site - System Information - PHP Information (example from 2.5)

[image: screenshot Joomla]

**Find your php.ini file** (search for php.ini in the PHP Information page, it should be under Loaded Configuration File), make a backup and then **add the following line** (adapted to your current needs; don't forget to remove the comment sign `;` before open_basedir):

`open_basedir = /home/users/you/public_html`

**Restart your web server (probably Apache).**

Now in Joomla! you should see the a value for `open_basedir`.

Make sure you test your Joomla! installation by trying some basic tasks, including updating an extension or installing a new one.

---

**More documentation can be found here:**

[Joomla! Documentation - Consider Using PHP open_basedir](http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/Hosting_and_Server_Setup#Consider_Using_PHP_open_basedir)

[php.net Documentation - open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Comment: This is the error Im getting - Can someone please find out what i need to do? http://202.169.196.16/~wwwevolv/

Comment: Read the error. It will tell you that you misconfigured the path.

Comment: Yeah i just dont know how to fix this. where do I edit the path? on the server? in a file somewhere?