# PHP timthumb error with Joomla

Tags: php, apache, joomla, timthumb

I am using a Joomla template in my site. But It doesn't load any images in portfolio content. When I am opening the path of the image it opens a php file and this gives this error

> open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs) is
>   not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in
>   ***serverpath***/public_html/templates/ekho/lib/timthumb.php on line 867

I need to know where is the problem? Please help in advance... Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772065/how-to-setup-open-basedir-in-php-for-joomla) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872674/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-path). And please provide the code that is on line 867 of that specific file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I need to know where's the php.ini file in my web server. I am using 000webhost. The php.ini file doesn't displaying in my file manager. Where's it? Please help me...

Comment: I've never used 000webhost before, so you would need to ask your host if you have access to it. If so, they will tell you where is it. If you don't have access to it, let me know and I will try to provide another solution.

Comment: I think I can't access to the PHP.ini file. (http://www.000webhost.com/forum/content-managament-systems/27651-edit-php-ini-000webhost.html) I used filezilla and searched everywhere for php.ini file. Also I searched in my site control panel. But I didn't find this file. But when I am using local server it works fine.  Please kindly provide me another solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is my error webpage: http://circuitworld.tk/index.php/2012-05-15-12-14-58/2012-06-09-14-00-10/category-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified timthumb.php designed to work with 00webhost:

[Pastebin:: timthumb.php](http://pastebin.com/7stJ6NUc)

Comment: OOPS! It worked!! Thanks so much... Special thanks for you and Lodder!!